# How do you create a for loop using a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input

I have a block of code under a div element "questionform" and want to allow the code to repeat, depending on the number of times the user would like it to, to eventually allow the user to make a quiz.
I have tried to create a bit of javascript in order to repeat just the question number for now, but it won't work.

```html
<div id="myHTMLWrapper">

</div>

<script>
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");

  var number = prompt("Enter the number of questions");

  for (var i = 0; i = number - 1; i++) {
    myHTML += '<span class="test">Question' + (i + 1) + '</span><br/><br/>';
  }

  wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML

</script>
```

any help will be appreciated, and please dont just point out flaws and not tell me how to improve them.

Comment: isn't `i < number` ? Since you already specified that `var i = 0`. Also, instantiate the variable `myHTML` before the loop

Comment: You get an error in your script because you're using the undeclared variable `myHTML`

Comment: Also, as @CalvinNunes mentions, the exit condition for the loop is wrong - it will not terminate.

Comment: so how do i make it right?  i have changed the i < number part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. firstly, you have to declare the variable *myHTML* outside the loop with empty string. Secondly, in the loop `i = number - 1` will prevent the iteration of the loop, try `i < number`

```html
<div id="myHTMLWrapper">

</div>

<script>
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");

  var number = prompt("Enter the number of questions");
  var myHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    myHTML += '<span class="test">Question ' + (i + 1) + '</span><br/><br/>';
  }

  wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML;

</script>
```

Though, here starting the loop iteration value from `1` with `i <= number` is more meaningful as this will allow you to use the value directly (without the increment) in the *htmlString*:

```html
<div id="myHTMLWrapper">

</div>

<script>
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");

  var number = prompt("Enter the number of questions");
  var myHTML = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    myHTML += '<span class="test">Question ' + i + '</span><br/><br/>';
  }

  wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML

</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, i see now. im such a beginner in coding so i appreciate this a lot